# How to punctuate this sentence with a semicolon?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, semicolons

How can I punctuate the following sentence? The semi-colon usage is nonstandard, since the second clause is dependent, but I'm not sure how else to do this besides an em-dash.

> The goal of this meeting is to plan the next phase of the construction
> project; particularly, to address the customer's concerns about the
> design of the kitchen.

Comment: The problem isn't the semi-colon: it's the word "particularly". I would write it, *The goal of this meeting is to plan the next phase of the construction project and, in particular, to address the customer's concerns about the design of the kitchen.*

Comment: Another option: The goal of this meeting is to plan the next phase of the construction project, specifically to address the customer's concern about the design of the kitchen.

Comment: And you could be a little old-fashioned and use a colon instead of a comma (plus a comma after _specifically_), with @gorlux's version.

Comment: Thank you! That solves it.